# wsimport .wsdl : why generating .class files and not .java files?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have a wsdl named as abc.wsdl

when I tried to generate the SEI Interface java files by this command

```
wsimport abc.wsdl
```

It generates .class files in package path a.b.c.d

but it has not generated any .java files .

Can you please tell me Why I was not able to generate the .java files ?

Actually I am new to .wsdl files.

Is it specified somewhere in .wsdl file to generate .class file and not .java file ?

**AND**

How I can generate .java file ?

Answer (score 50):

`wsimport` utility from JDK 1.7 does generate `java` files but removes them after byte-code generation leaving `class` files only. You can use option `-keep` to specify that you want to have both.

```
wsimport -keep http://example.com/webservice?wsdl
```

Answer (score 40):

If you don't need classes, you can use `-Xnocompile` option of wsimport tool.

Answer (score 15):

By default wsimport generates only classes but it can be used to generate sources too with -s flag.
For example make a folder *src* to your to-be-generated classes root folder and execute a command like this:

```
wsimport -s src http://example.com/webservice?wsdl
```

This way your classes will be as before but your sources will be on src folder.
Additional info about different wsimport flags can be found by entering wsimport -help on command line.